# Using Telegram Web inside Tor Browser: Log-in attempts fail several times?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, error, browsers, login

When trying to log-in to my Telegram account on [web.telegram.org](https://web.telegram.org) I get requested to insert my phone number as usual. The next step would be insertion of a log-in authentification code that I receive on other Telegram instances.

Instead of switching forward to the insertion field for that code I always receive the following error dialog:

```
Too fast
You are performing too many actions. Please try again later.
Click for technical details
```

So I click on "Click for technical details" and see the following description:

```
Method: auth.sendCode
Result: {"_":"rpc_error","error_code":420,"error_message":"FLOOD_WAIT_86400"}
```

However, log-in to Telegram Web in common webbrowsers (Firefox, Chrome, etc.) works completely fine. Only the Tor Browser seems to cause this error.

---

Does any Tor user have similar issues with Telegram web?

Answer (score 1):

> Sometimes websites will block Tor users because they can't tell the difference between the average Tor user and some malicious or automated traffic.

Source: [My favorite website is blocking access over Tor!](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/teams/CommunityTeam/Support#MyfavoritewebsiteisblockingaccessoverTor)

Wait for an hour and try again. You might also want to try [Telegram Desktop](https://desktop.telegram.org/).

### See also

[Google makes me solve a CAPTCHA or tells me I have spyware installed.](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#GoogleCAPTCHA)